# Why does multithreaded version take the same amount of time as single threaded version?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following work queue implementation, which I use to limit the number of threads in use. It works by me initially adding a number of Runnable objects to the queue, and when I am ready to begin, I run "begin()". At this point I do not add any more to the queue.

```
public class WorkQueue {

    private final int nThreads;
    private final PoolWorker[] threads;
    private final LinkedList queue;
    Integer runCounter;
    boolean hasBegun;

    public WorkQueue(int nThreads) {
        runCounter = 0;
        this.nThreads = nThreads;
        queue = new LinkedList();
        threads = new PoolWorker[nThreads];
        hasBegun = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
            threads[i] = new PoolWorker();
            threads[i].start();
        }
    }

    public boolean isQueueEmpty() {
        synchronized (queue) {
            if (queue.isEmpty() && runCounter == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void begin() {
        hasBegun = true;
        synchronized (queue) {
            queue.notify();
        }
    }

    public void add(Runnable r) {
        if (!hasBegun) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                queue.addLast(r);
                runCounter++;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("has begun executing. Cannot add more jobs ");
        }
    }

    private class PoolWorker extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            Runnable r;

            while (true) {
                synchronized (queue) {
                    while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            queue.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                        }
                    }

                    r = (Runnable) queue.removeFirst();
                }

                // If we don't catch RuntimeException, 
                // the pool could leak threads
                try {
                    r.run();
                    synchronized (runCounter) {
                        runCounter--;
                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    // You might want to log something here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a runnable I use to keep track of when all the jobs on the work queue have finished:

```
public class QueueWatcher implements Runnable {

    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    private WorkQueue wq;

    public QueueWatcher(WorkQueue wq) {
        this.threadName = "QueueWatcher";
        this.wq = wq;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (wq.isQueueEmpty()) {
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                System.out.println("Finishing and quiting at:" + date.toString());
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PlaneGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        wq.begin();

        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.setDaemon(false);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I use them:

```
Workqueue wq = new WorkQueue(9); //Get same results regardless of 1,2,3,8,9
QueueWatcher qw = new QueueWatcher(wq);

SomeRunnable1 sm1 = new SomeRunnable1();
SomeRunnable2 sm2 = new SomeRunnable2();
SomeRunnable3 sm3 = new SomeRunnable3();
SomeRunnable4 sm4 = new SomeRunnable4();
SomeRunnable5 sm5 = new SomeRunnable5();

wq.add(sm1);
wq.add(sm2);
wq.add(sm3);
wq.add(sm4);
wq.add(sm5);

qw.start();
```

But regardless of how many threads I use, the result is always the same - it always takes about 1m 10seconds to complete. This is about the same as when I just did a single threaded version (when everything ran in main()).
If I set wq to (1,2,3--9) threads it is always between 1m8s-1m10s. What is the problem ? The jobs (someRunnable) have nothing to do with each other and cannot block each other.

EDIT: Each of the runnables just read some image files from the filesystems and create new files in a separate directory. The new directory eventually contains about 400 output files.

EDIT: It seems that only one thread is always doing work. I made the following changes:

I let the Woolworker store an Id

```
    PoolWorker(int id){
        this.threadId = id;
    }
```

Before running I print the id of the worker.

```
                System.out.println(this.threadId + " got new task");
                r.run();
```

In WorkQueue constructor  when creating the poolworkers I do:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        threads[i] = new PoolWorker(i);
        threads[i].start();
    }
```

But it seems that that only thread 0 does any work, as the output is always:

> 0 got new task

Comment: What do the Runnables do?

Comment: The Runnables read different image files from a directory and create new output files (modified images). The input files are not modified, and no runnable uses the same output file.

Comment: Even though they don't touch the same file, they may be blocked on disk I/O. Try adding some timing logs to your PoolWorker (include the thread name in the log) so you can see more details - do they slow down with more threads? Do they actually run in parallel?

Comment: It makes no difference - if I use anywhere between 1 - 9 threads, it always takes about 1m8s - 1m10s.

Comment: The runnables basically take 6 input files, and generate 400 from them by cutting them up / processing them etc. I don't think the reads should be blocked, and each write is to a separate file. Also 1-9 threads seems really low to block disk i/o.

Comment: It seems that for some reason, only one thread is running.

Comment: On a side note, synchronizing on `Integer runCounter` isn't doing what you think it's doing - `runCounter++` is actually assigning a new value to the `Integer` each time, so you're synchronizing on a lot of different `Integer` objects.  If you're doing multithreading, I recommend looking into `Executors` and the concurrency package that manages a lot of that stuff for you.

Comment: you're right. A blunder. Let me try to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `queue.notifyAll()` to start processing.

Currently you're using `queue.notify()`, which will only wake a single thread.  (The big clue that pointed me to this was when you mentioned only a single thread was running.)

Also, synchronizing on `Integer runCounter` isn't doing what you think it's doing - `runCounter++` is actually assigning a new value to the `Integer` each time, so you're synchronizing on a lot of different `Integer` objects.

---

On a side note, using raw threads and `wait/notify` paradigms is complicated and error-prone even for the best programmers - it's why Java introduced the [`java.util.concurrent` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), which provide threadsafe `BlockingQueue` implementations and `Executors` for easily managing multithreaded apps.